# How to recall items from favourites table

Tags: php, mysql, database, get, posts

I have a table of favourites with 'id' 'userid' and 'postid'. I'm trying to select all the entries in 'postid' when 'userid' = 1 for example.

I also have a table of posts with 'id' and others of content. I then want to select all the rows where a 'postid'='id' and then echo the content of those rows.

Essentially filtering the posts by which have been favourited by the user.

What I've got is

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$user = $_SESSION['id'];
$getfaves = mysql_query("SELECT postid FROM Favourites where userid='$user'") or die(mysql_query());
if ($rowfave = mysql_fetch_assoc($getfaves))
    {
        $faveposts = $rowfave['id'];

        $getposts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Posts where id='$faveposts' ORDER BY id DESC");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getposts))
        {
            $content = 'content';
            echo ($content);
        }
    }
?>
```

(the $content = 'content'; is just an example, it's not what I'm actually using in my code)

Obviously this is incorrect, probably because I want to select a list of ids and then search for everything in that list, but I've only coded to look for one item. However I don't know how to correct this.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: What is the schema of `posts`? Is `id` the user id or the id of the post?

Comment: in posts, 'id' is the id of the post

Comment: The code looks correct then, what are you actually printing in second loop? If you print the row you should see the post correctly

Comment: You can use this query "SELECT * FROM Posts where id IN (SELECT postid FROM Favourites where userid='$user') ORDER BY id DESC"

Comment: @Fabio just an image and some text, nothing that should be causing a problem.

Comment: I don't understand, what is your actual problem?

Comment: @JayaVishwakarma that works, but only for 1 post. Even if there are multiple favourites, it only shows 1

Comment: @Fabio Problem is currently that JayaVashwakarma 's solution will successfully recall 1 of the favourited posts, which is great, but only 1, seemingly ignoring the rest...

Comment: @Codedstuff Are you sure your first query returns you more than 1 row?

Comment: @JayaVishwakarma yep, definitely should. Double checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a more simple way to do that using just one sql query with the help of `INNER JOIN`.
so your query will be

```
SELECT POST.*
FROM `Favourites`
INNER JOIN `Post`
ON Post.id = Favourites.postid WHERE (Favourites.userid='$user')
ORDER BY Post.id DESC;
```

[here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) is doc about `INNER JOIN` and its utilities

**Please let me know if you need more help,**

the php part:

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$user = $_SESSION['id'];
$sql="SELECT POST.*
    FROM `Favourites`
    INNER JOIN `Post`
    ON Post.id = Favourites.postid WHERE (Favourites.userid='$user')
    ORDER BY Post.id DESC";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dataBase);
  $Result = $conn->query($sql);
  while($row = $Result->fetch_assoc()) {
    //do what you want with the $row, it contain ur resault
  }
?>
```

**feel free to test it and report the problem if there is one**

Comment: Thanks, will give that a go. How would I format that as a mysql_query as I have done in my original code? Sorry if dumb question, still pretty new to php

Comment: just put in in variable like so->
$sql = "SELECT POST.*
FROM `Favourites`
INNER JOIN `Post`
ON Post.id = Favourites.postid WHERE (Favourites.userid='$user')
ORDER BY Post.id DESC";

**i will edit my answer to cover the php part**

Comment: Thanks. I know it's best practice to use PDO, but I'm more comfortable without it

Comment: ok you can use whatever type of connection just make sure that you put the sql query i gave you inside a variable (in my example its $sql)

Comment: `$getposts= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Favourites` INNER JOIN `Post` ON Post.id = Favourites.postid WHERE (Favourites.userid='$user')ORDER BY Post.id DESC");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getposts));` is what I've got. Definitely not right, get internal server error. Evidently I'm not adapting it correctly...

Comment: Using the `mysql_query()` function, you're creating a new statement for every insert and you may be exceeding the allowed limit.
so im afraid that your code will never be succeeded , try using the code i've posted, its not PDO its just mysqli instead of mysql_query, let me know if you've followed the instruction i've posted in the last comment.

Comment: Ah, don't worry, I've got it. Sometimes it takes me a little while haha. Works brilliantly now, thanks!

Comment: Just needed to do some minor tweaks: $sql="SELECT Posts.*
      FROM `Favourites`
      INNER JOIN `Posts`
      ON Posts.id = Favourites.postid WHERE (Favourites.userid='$profileid')
      ORDER BY Posts.id DESC";
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {}

Comment: Was giving me errors as not recognising the tables, but all sorted now. Thanks for all your help.